# My bash script to safely delete files doesn't work with more than one file. I don't know why

Tags: bash, iteration

I am trying to make a delete script which uses regex to move all matching files to a Trash folder in my home directory. I want to be able to use the same syntax as the vanilla rm command, but without it deleting it permanently. I can't seem to get it to run through all the matching files in the pwd. It will move one file, then exit. Here is my script.

```
file=$1

for i in $file; do
        mv "$file" "/home/totallykvothe/Trash/$i"
done

exit 0
```

Pretty simple. I don't know why it isn't working. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `./yourscript *.txt`, `*.txt` isn't just one argument that's put into `$1`; instead, it's a glob that's expanded by the shell (to be clear -- not the shell **running** your script, but the shell **that starts** your script) into a *list* of arguments. The first goes in `$1`, the second in `$2`, etc.

Thus:

```
for i in "$@"; do
  mv -- "$i" "/home/totallykvothe/Trash/$i"
done
```

Comment: So "$@" then just points to the current directory?

Never mind. I got it. Thank you! this solved my problem